# Blocking an event on the input range element with ctrl-key pressed

Tags: javascript, firefox, events

When moving the mouse with the ctrl-key initially held on the input range element, the movement and processing of the input or change event are blocked in Firefox (windows 10), in Chrome everything is ok.

Perhaps there is some way around this using javascript?

I want the range step to change when the ctrl-key is pressed and the mouse moves left and right, as it happens with the wheel event:

```js
  const input = document.querySelector("input");
  const currentStep = document.querySelector(".current-step");
  currentStep.textContent = input.min;

  input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    const target = event.target;

    currentStep.textContent = target.value;
  });

  input.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();

    const target = event.target;

    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      target.step = 0.01;
    } else {
      target.step = 0.25;
    }
  });
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0.25" max="5.5" step="0.25" value="0" />
<div class="current-step">0</div>
```

Comment: In macOS + Firefox 119, I can't reproduce the issue.